# HiLow Computer Generated Guessing Game

Tags: c++

I have to create a HiLow game where the user has to guess the random number generated by the computer. I have to implement at least one function, to check the number I guess. And output how many guesses it took to get the answer right. The game works, but I do not have a couple of things, I need to output an error message if the user enters a number out of range and to output the number of guesses it took to get the correct answer. I am not sure where to get started. Here is my code so far.

Requirements from professor: Write the Console Application Program or Game called HiLow. In this game the computer generates a random number with values ranging from 1 to 100. Then it asks the user for their guess. If the player guesses high or low, the computer gives back Too High or Too Low and asks for a new guess. When the correct answer is given, the player is congratulated, told how many guesses it took to get the right answer, and asked to play again.Tell the user to enter –1 for a guess when they want to quit playing.Implement one function. –

```
// Angela Mansfield
// Assignment HiLow
// CIS 227
// 9/23/16

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using std::getline;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl; 
using std::string;


// check number method add all of work here call from main
double numCheck() {
    int num = rand();
    int guess;

    //sets random number to the variable num 
    srand(time(NULL));
    num = rand() % 100 + 1;

    do {
        cout << "Pick a number 1-100: ";            //can I check the number here??
        cin >> guess;
        //have to enter number 2 times
        if (num < guess) {cout << "Too High" << endl;}
        else if (num > guess) {cout << "Too Low" << endl;}
        else if (num = guess) {cout << "Congratulations you guessed correctly!!" << endl;}
    } while (guess != -1);


    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    numCheck();


}
```

Comment: Sorry, my Vulcan Mind Meld doesn't work at far distances.  What are these *extras* you are talking about?  (Please modify your post.)

Comment: You should tell the User how to quit the program, like entering "-1".

Comment: For a more difficult game, you should *seed* the random number generator so it doesn't use the same sequence each time.

Comment: I highly recommend you get in the habit of using braces, '{}` after `if` statements.  It will prevent nasty defects from being injected.  Many coding guidelines demand this.

Comment: Also, remove the "stdafx.h" and choose a configuration for your projects that don't use *precompiled headers*.  For small programs, the precompiled header feature may be more burdensome.

Comment: Please post the requirements of the `numCheck` function.  Talk to your instructor if you don't understand or have incomplete requirements.

Comment: I took all of the code in the main and added it to a function abouve and called it in the main, but now I need to make sure the uses guesses a number between 1-100 and send an error message if needed and output how many guesses it took them to get the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Before you work on the extras, lets get started with fixing the program.

## What is wrong?

1. **`=` operator vs. `==` operator**

   `else if (num = guess) cout <<"Congratulations you guessed corectly!!" << endl;`

`num = guess` will ssign `guess` to `num` and return true. That will make sure you get this output on the first time, if no other input were chosen.

2. **user experience / logic exception**

   `while (guess != -1);`

well, you ask a user to guess from 1 to 100 and wait till they hit the -1. that's kinda cruel.

3. **uninitialized input**

   `int guess;`

compilers use to yell at you if you don't initialize these before you input.

## How to fix?

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int guess = 0;                           // Problem 3

    do {
        cout << "Pick a number 1-100: ";
        cin >> guess;
        if (num == guess)                    // Problem 1
            cout <<"Congratulations! you guessed corectly!!" << endl;
        else if (num < guess) 
            cout <<"Too High" << endl;
        else 
            cout <<"Too Low" << endl;
        } 
    while (guess != num);                    // Problem 2   

    return 0;
}
```

---

Now you can move on to continue with adding some more features.

Comment: The -1 is to exit the program. I tried it your way and it no longer worked.

Comment: ok, so change it back. but i would normally expect the program to terminate when the user enters the right choice, and not wait for him to input -1.

Comment: It is what my teacher wants. Thank you for your help.